# Fatal error: @SceneStorage is only for use with SwiftUI App Lifecycle.: file SwiftUI, line 0

Tags: swiftui, ios14, xcode12

I'm trying to use the new property wrapper for iOS 14 "SceneStorage" though it is producing this error:

> Fatal error: @SceneStorage is only for use with SwiftUI App
> Lifecycle.: file SwiftUI, line 0

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @SceneStorage("isLoggedIn") var isLoggedIn = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!).onAppear {
            print($isLoggedIn)
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated....**
Thanks, @Asperi!.
Make sure you set the *Life Cycle* to **SwiftUI App**.

[image]

Comment: Hello Gerard, I'm working with xcode 14 have the same warning but I do not find the location to set the Live Cycle to SwiftUI. Where do I have to look? Do I need to create a new project or can I change the existing one to SwiftUI?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine with Xcode 12 / iOS 14 / SwiftUI Life-cycle

It looks like your project uses SwiftUI 1.0 `AppDelegate/SceneDelegate` (aka UIKit Life-cycle)

In SwiftUI Life-cycle your app main should be like

```
@main
struct YourAppName: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {       // << this introduces Scene, needed for SceneStorage
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had the Life Cycle when creating the Project set to UIKit App Delegate.  Setting it to SwiftUI App fixed it.